# Rock, Paper, Scissors game: the loop in my code keeps giving me the same random result

Tags: javascript

I am creating a rock, paper, scissors games and just testing out my unfinished code. The game is between the user and the computer.

As you can see, `computerSelection` will generate a random "rock", "paper", or "scissors". The issue is that without refreshing the page, every time I type "rock" in the prompt and hit OK, I get the same console.log message in a loop: "Good job! Rock Beats Scissors" or "Sorry! paper beats Rock". In other words, the game has become one-sided; every time I type in "rock" and hit OK, either I always win or the computer always wins.

UPDATE: I have revised my code, but another issue I have is that sometimes the code repeats in console.log, not adding any score. If you look at the screenshot, it has repeated the code 2 times, but did not add a score.

[image]

```
const playerSelection = ''
const computerSelection = computerPlay()
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))

function computerPlay(){
  let values = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
  valueToUse = values [Math.floor(Math.random()* values.length)];
  return valueToUse;
};

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  while(true){
    playerSelection = prompt ('Pick your poison');

    if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock' && computerPlay() === 'paper'){
      computerScore += 1
      console.log('Sorry! Paper beats Rock')
    } 
    else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock'.toLowerCase() && computerPlay() === 'scissors'){
      playerScore += 1
      console.log('Good job! Rock beats Scissors');
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log('Please type Rock, Paper, or Scissors')
    }

  console.log (`User Selection: ${playerSelection.toUpperCase()} | Player Score: ${playerScore} 
Computer Selection: ${computerSelection.toUpperCase()} | Computer Score: ${computerScore}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `computerPlay()` in the loop.

Comment: Why is `playerSelection` a parameter of the function? It never uses the parameter, it asks the user for a value instead.

Comment: Just think about it logically -- how do you expect `computerSelection` to change if you never reassign it?

Comment: `playRound` doesn't return anything. Why are you logging the result?

Comment: Based on the name, `playRound()` should just play *one* round of the game, it shouldn't have a loop inside it. You should call it in a loop, and the caller should get the new player and computer selections.

Comment: Thank you. I actually assigned computerPlay() to the variable, computerSelection. Out of curiosity, why can't I call computerSelection instead?

Comment: You only assigned it once, not each time through the loop, like you did with `playerSelection`.

Comment: *comment to your UPDATE:*  point counting is working well, the only rounds that don't change the score are the ones with a 'tie' (when both the computer and player pick 'rock').

Answer (score 2):

The following changes to the code will make it work:

1. Declaring `computerSelection` the same way as `playerSelection`.

New version:

```
const playerSelection = ''
const computerSelection = ''
```

Original version:

```
const playerSelection = ''
const computerSelection = computerPlay()
```

2. Calling the function `computerPlay()` within the `playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)` function, hence assigning a value to the `computerSelection` variable each time the player makes their pick, as well.

New version:

```
playerSelection= prompt ('Pick your...');
computerSelection = computerPlay();
```

Original version:

```
 playerSelection= prompt ('Pick your...');
```

(Disclaimer: I've tried to stay as close to the original code as possible.)

Comment: In addition, I'd suggest to cover the case where the computerSelection is 'rock' (for now, as per the 'else' clause in your code, it would say 'Please type Rock, Paper, or Scissors' even in case the player had actually done that.)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it asks "Please type Rock, Paper, or Scissors". Why it does that? I thought the else clause was supposed to fix this

Comment: It's because the code only distinguishes 3 cases:  1) Player = 'rock' & Computer = 'paper',   2) Player = 'rock' & Computer = 'scissors'  and   3) everything else  (as per console.log message, this is meant for incorrect input from the player). The situation Player = 'rock' & Computer = 'rock' is not specifically covered, hence it falls into the 'everything else' category too.

Comment: You can add the following 'else if' clause to your code:  `else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock'.toLowerCase() && computerSelection === 'rock'){console.log('Tie!');}`